# What is wrong with my http header?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I am trying to send http header to browser after I establish connection between server and browser:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)
print "Listening for connections on port %d" % PORT

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print 'New connection received'
    handle_client(client_socket)
```

my code for sending the header:

```
data = get_file_data('index.html')
header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf 8\r\n\r\n' + data
client_socket.sendall(header)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You tell what the problem is :) So far I cat tell you are missing Content-Encoding and/or Content-Length.

Comment: Do you mean charset=utf-8? Also you have extra space before Content-Type header

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the `Content-Length` and `Connection: close` headers.

You can use `len(data)` for the content length in your case.

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens in the browser after the connection is establish. I want to see the html page that i am sending from the server. i tried to add the Content-Length and it was not the problem.

Comment: Try and add `Connection: close` as a header

Comment: Thank you, now something is working, but I don't see the css and the js parts of the html page properly, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You must add `Content-Length:` in your http header.
You can use this line code:

```
data = get_file_data('index.html')
header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf 8\r\n\r\n%s' % (len(data), data)
client_socket.sendall(header)
```

Comment: its working but the css code is not, do you have idea way?